# How to make cv2.videoCapture run faster for a CSI camera

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer, opencv, nvidia-jetson-nano, python

I'm running a CSI camera on Nvidia Jetson Nano board. The camera streaming is done via GStreamer. Everything works fine but I wanted to reduce the time for opening the GStreamer channel. It takes more than 1 sec to open the GStreamer channel (cv2.VideoCapture(cam)). I can reduce the resolution but I wanted to capture images at the highest resolution. Here is the snippet

```
camSet='nvarguscamerasrc !  video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=3264, height=2464, format=NV12, framerate=21/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method='+str(flip)+' ! video/x-raw, width='+str(dispW)+', height='+str(dispH)+', format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink'
start_time = time.time()
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camSet)
print("Elpsed Time", time.time() - start_time)
```

> Elapsed Time 1.0194542407989502

Is there any way to reduce this time?

Comment: Here was the solution I came up with on the Nvidia forums: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/optimizing-opencv-gstreamer-with-mipi-and-usb-uvc-cameras/123665/27